# Unity 2D Setting the Sprite Renderers sorting layers in fixed update efficiency

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Excuse me if the question was already asked, but I'm still fairly new to things and am a bit worried about what the best approach is to setting the sorting layer based on position as its running a few calculations in the fixed update function. The case is for a 2d game, top down with sprites rendering on top or under each other.

```
public class RendererUpdate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject omniObject;
    public int fineTune = 0;

    public bool isMoving;

    // assign child objects to
    public List<SpriteRenderer> childRendererFront;
    public List<SpriteRenderer> childRendererBack;

    private new SpriteRenderer renderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        renderer = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!isMoving) { return; }

        var sortOrder = (int)(omniObject.transform.position.y * -100) + fineTune;
        renderer.sortingOrder = sortOrder;
        childRendererBack.ForEach(x => x.sortingOrder = sortOrder - 1);
        childRendererFront.ForEach(x => x.sortingOrder = sortOrder + 1);
    }
}
```

Right now it is just running on a few objects but I would still like to improve it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any graphics related operations should be executed on render thread, for example in `Update` function. Although the code above may seem innocent, these callbacks can become expensive and may lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure whether to use fixed or update, I thought since fixed is only called per every fixed framerate it would be more efficient